# error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string when use guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle to make a get request and I have a Json response. I tried to pass that Json response to my view but get a error like title. 
Here is my controller:

```
class RestApi extends Controller
{
    public  function request() {
        $endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data?taskId=21159";
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $taskId = 21159;

        $response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['auth' => ['kermit','kermit']]);

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        $formData = $content['formProperties'];

        return view('formData')->with('formData', $formData);
    }

}
```

When I use dd(formData), the data is not null:

[image]

In my view, I just want to check my formData is passed or not:

```
@if(isset($formData))
    @foreach($formData as $formDataValue)
    {{ $formDataValue }}
    @endforeach
    @endif
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/response','RestApi@request')->middleware('cors');
```

How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `dd($formData)` in your view. Do you see your array there?

Comment: I showed in my post, there are arrays...

Comment: That is a `dd` you put inside controllers method. I mean to check if data is passed correctly to the view. So I asked to `dd($formData)` in your view.

Comment: oh it have arrays same like in my post... but why I can display it with that code in my view?

Comment: okay I fixed... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to display the array `{{ $formDataValue }}` directly

`{{ }}` this will support only string

it supposed to be like this for example:

```
@if(isset($formData))
    <ul>
    @foreach($formData as $formDataValue)
        <li>ID : {{ $formDataValue['id'] }}</li>
        <li>Name : {{ $formDataValue['name'] }}</li>
        <li>Type : {{ $formDataValue['type'] }}</li>
        .
        .
        .
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: sorry for annoying but last element in my array have another array, how I can display it. I use {{ $formDataValue['enumValues']['id'] }} but it say "Undefined index: id"

Comment: `$formDataValue['enumValues']` is multi dimensional array, so again you should make another `foreach` like `foreach ($formDataValue['enumValues'] as $enumValues) {
    $enumValues['id']
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have another array here:
[image]

So,

```php
@if(isset($formData)) //$formData is an array of arrays
    @foreach($formData as $formDataValue)
        {{ $formDataValue }} //$formDataValue is still an array, so it fails
    @endforeach
@endif
```

`{{ }}` accepts only string.

You have to iterate once more:

```php
@foreach($formData as $formDataItem)
    @foreach($formDataItem as $item)
        //here $item would be a string such as "id", "name", "type", but can also be an array ("enumValues")
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Finally

```php
@foreach($formData as $formDataItem)
    @foreach($formDataItem as $item)
        @if(is_array($item))
            @foreach($item as $i) //iterate once more for cases like "enumValues"
                //here you'll have one of "enumValues" array, you have to iterate it again :)
            @endforeach
        @else
            {{ $item }} //you can render a string like "id", "name", "type", ...
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```